# ACR: Quick Color Preview While Using "B&W Mixer" tool for Black and White Photo?

Tags: black-and-white, adobe-camera-raw

In Adobe Camera Raw, when using a monochrome color profile, we get the B&W Mixer tool:
[image: Photo of B&W Mixer tool in Adobe Camera Raw]

When using this tool, I wish I could quickly enter a keyboard shortcut and see a quick color preview of the image.

**Is there a quick and easy way to see a color preview of an image with a monochrome color profile in Adobe Camera Raw, without changing the color profile?**

### Research

[Lightroom B&W Mix: how to see where the original colors are?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82953/lightroom-bw-mix-how-to-see-where-the-original-colors-are) - this post is about seeing where certain colors are in Lightroom, which is similar, but not the same as my question. I'm interested in seeing the entire image in color briefly, not seeing a mask of a selected color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my computer when I am in ACR and do B/W conversion when press "`\`" I get colour image. Second press of the same button return me to B/W version.

P.S. Same work for me in Lightroom (as before and after)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this, and both have keyboard shortcuts...

The before after comparison has options in the preference settings for how you want them displayed (e.g. side by side), and the after image will update as you change settings/edit. This is often more useful than the next option depending on why you want to see the colors.

The other option is to switch between the default processing (applied when first opened) and the current state.

If you forget the shortcut, just hover the mouse pointer over those buttons and a description w/ the shortcut will pop up (same for most of the other buttons as well).

[image]

Comment: Steven, for the right icon the key is back slash  \ , not slash  /